# Best approach to calculation problem

Tags: sql-server, performance, powerbi, query-performance

I am re-developing an application that has been running on Excel. One of the reports I need to recreate (which will be published in Power BI and needs to be a direct query) is as follows;

[image]

Column "Approved Est" is calculated from a specific table, so is "Rec Value Based on Ordered Works".  Column "+/- Approved Est" is a simple calculation based on the first two.   This is where i need advice.  There are many ways I know of to get the result, and here is what I have considered or tried.

1) Create a function that has a temporary table holding the initial columns so I can run one update that calculates the reliant columns without having to do the select for the original columns again, and ultimately returns one table.

2) Create a view with multiple unions that calculates each column.  Down side is that I have to re-run the select for the original columns to give the calculated ones.

3) Create separate functions that return the calculated value for any address

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Could you add an schema (CREATE TABLE) and INSERTS just to generate a minimal verifiable example?

Comment: I will do, hopefully tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PowerBI DirectQuery you'll need to write a single view that returns all the data.  Internally you might use a table-valued function if that is convenient.

If the execution of the queries against the view is too expensive, you'll have to cache the results, either by loading them into a table, or by switching from DirectQuery to Import mode.

David

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am fine with the Power BI piece, it's the best approach to creating efficient SQL that I am struggling with.